# How to Read the CSV file which has two data set (I.e Two Different Header and Column)

Tags: powershell

I have CSV file which has two sets of data (Two Different Header and Column value) as below,

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Last_Data_Refresh,Run_Date,Type  
Data1,Data2,Data3,12/08/2019 08:49:07,12/08/2019 08:59:27,Yes

Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header17,date  
Data1,Data2,Data3,Data4,Data17,01/05/2019 08:59:27 AM
ABC1,ABC2,ABC3,ABC4,ABC17,12/12/2018 08:59:27 AM
XYZ1,XYZ2,XYZ3,XYZ4,XYZ17,03/05/2019 08:59:27 PM
```

I want to read the CSV data and exclude the Last_Data_Refresh,Run_Date column in Data Set 1.

I have tried the below code, but it excludes the whole line instead of particular column,

```
Get-content  "$file"|
Select-String  -notmatch -pattern '[0-3][0-9]/[01][0-9]/[0-9]{4} [0-2]?[0-9]:[0-6]?[0-9]:[0-6]?[0-9],'
```

Is there a way that powershell can import and read the csvfile as below, for two data set within one CSV file and exclude the Last_Data_Refresh,Run_Date in Data set 1

Column1 : Data1
Column2 : Data2
Column3 : Data3

...

Type : Yes

Header1 : ABC1
Header2 : ABC2
Header3 : ABC3
Header4 : ABC4
...
Header17: ABC17
date    : 12/12/2018 08:59:27 AM

Comment: i  don't understand what you are talking about. [*blush*] do you want the two input CSV files combined into ONE csv file? if so, please show the output CSV file that would result from your two input CSV files.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey,  I have one CSV file which has two sets of data, i want to exclude two columns from Data set 1 and list all the columns from Data set 2 (Both Data set has been separated by new empty line )

Comment: you cannot have two sets of data in a CSV file. [*grin*] if you have different sets of data ... then that is NOT a CSV file - it's a text file.///// so ... split the file into two REAL csv data files and then use `Import-CSV` to import each file, use `Select-Object` to grab only the wanted columns, and `Export-CSV` to send the two data sets out. if you really want to trash the CSV files and  make that defective text file, you can simply merge them with `Get-Content`.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I agree, The Real CSV file should not have two data set, but this is an exceptional case and i don't have control to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you have as input is definitively NOT valid CSV as already commented. 
In order to use as proper CSV, you need to split the file into two parts.

Your question is also quite vague as to what you eventually want to do with these parts, maybe save them as proper CSV files?

Anyway, this should get you going:

```
# Read the file as a single string with the '-Raw' switch
$crappyCsv = Get-Content -Path 'D:\input.csv' -Raw  # -Raw reads the file as a single string

# Split on the first empty line because that seems to be what separates the CSV blocks
$part1, $part2 = $crappyCsv -split '\r?\n\r?\n', 2

# Convert the parts you have as objects and exclude the columns you don't want
$csv1 = $part1 | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty Last_Data_Refresh, Run_Date
$csv2 = $part2 | ConvertFrom-Csv

# I have no idea what you eventually want to do with these parts, maybe save them as propert CSV files?

# Output on screen
Write-Host "First CSV" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$csv1 | Format-Table -AutoSize

Write-Host "Second CSV" -ForegroundColor Yellow
$csv2 | Format-Table -AutoSize

# Save as files
$csv1 | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\FirstCsv.csv'  -NoTypeInformation -Force
$csv2 | Export-Csv -Path 'D:\SecondCsv.csv' -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Output on screen:

> ```
> First CSV
>
> Column1 Column2 Column3 Type 
> ------- ------- ------- -----
> Data1   Data2   Data3   Yes  
>
>
> Second CSV
>
> Header1 Header2 Header3 Header4 Header17 date                  
> ------- ------- ------- ------- -------- -----                 
> Data1   Data2   Data3   Data4   Data17   01/05/2019 08:59:27 AM
> ABC1    ABC2    ABC3    ABC4    ABC17    12/12/2018 08:59:27 AM
> XYZ1    XYZ2    XYZ3    XYZ4    XYZ17    03/05/2019 08:59:27 PM
> ```

Comment: Thank you.  I want to compare the  crappyCsv file with another crappyCsv file and spit the difference out in another text file.  I want to ignore  Last_Data_Refresh, Run_Date column in comparison.   I will try the above method. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

In CSV files you can have only single set of data.
column names and data bellow. If you add more data on the next row it will be part of the same data set.

You have 2 approaches that can take:
1. Split the file to 2 and have separate CSV files for each set
2. Use more columns and glue the data sets as this: Column1,Column2,Column3,Last_Data_Refresh,Run_Date,Type,Header1,Header2,Header3,Header4,Header17,date